# Returning nullable values from a method using terniary operator

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm having some difficulty returning a nullable type from a method using the ?: operator.

For example, this works:

```
    public static Int32? RunInt32Query(string query, KeyValueCollection parameters)
    {
        object scalar = RunScalarQuery(query, parameters);

        if (scalar != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(scalar);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But this examples does not work, it will not compile:

```
    public static Int32? RunInt32Query(string query, KeyValueCollection parameters)
    {
        object scalar = RunScalarQuery(query, parameters);

        return (scalar != null) ? Convert.ToInt32(scalar) : null;
    }
```

As I understood it, both methods are doing virtually the same thing at a high level, but apparently not?

Comment: what you meant by `does not work`

Comment: @un-lucky It will not compile in the second example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
return (scalar != null) ? (Int32?)Convert.ToInt32(scalar) : null;
```

---

In

```
return Convert.ToInt32(scalar);
```

The compiler knows that the target type is `Int32?` (based upon the method declaration) and thus can automatically convert the result of the expression `Convert.ToInt32(scalar)` based upon the implicit conversion.

With the conditional operator, the compiler first tries to determine the type of the expression `(scalar != null) ? Convert.ToInt32(scalar) : null`. For this purpose, it evaluates the types of the two result expressions, `Convert.ToInt32(scalar)` and `null`. Those types are `Int32` and `Object`, respectively. It is not obvious to the compiler that both expressions can be converted to `Int32?`.